# TuneLength in R caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret

I'm following a `caret` package tutorial in R with the `Sonar` built-in dataset. This dataset is composed by 208 rows and 61 features/variables (60 if the class is discarded).

In a step, it explains the `trainControl` and `train` function as follows:

```
# Model training controller (cross-validation with 3 reps)
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", repeats=3)

myModel <- train (Class ~ ., 
           data=train_partition,
           method="pls",
           preProc=c("scale"),
           trControl=control,
           tuneLength=3)
```

When I show the `train` documentation the `tuneLength` parameter is specified as:

```
An integer denoting the amount of granularity in the tuning parameter grid. 
By default, this argument is the number of levels for each tuning parameters that 
should be generated by train. If trainControl has the option search = "random", 
this is the maximum number of tuning parameter combinations that will be generated 
by the random search. (NOTE: If given, this argument must be named.)
```

What is/are these "tuning parameter(s)" of method "pls" specified in the first line of the documentation?

Why can I set this parameter to a value in the range 1-50? What means this parameter?

Comment: You can look up models in the `caret` documentation, see https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#partial-least-squares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Tuning parameters" in *caret* refers to the hyper parameters, whose value you need to provide to an algorithm before it begins learning.

*Partial Least Squares* (`'pls'`), has a hyper parameter: `'ncomp'` i.e the number of components/ latent factors. In theory, you can have as many component as the number of features/ variables in your data-set. For *Sonar* data you have 60 features.

In practicality, due to redundant features you need less number of components that explain considerable variance in model. Therefore you are tuning between 1 to 50 to evaluate for best performance.